# Conda install outside of base

Tags: conda

I accidentally installed some packages using conda install without activating any virtual environment (not even base as I turned the auto-activate feature of conda off). May I know where are the packages installed? Are they installed outside of conda or still within conda environments, most likely base?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you deactivate conda and try a command like "conda list", the Terminal will show the package list of the base environment. So, when you use "conda install" without activating any environment, the package will be installed to the base environment.